# Store the user searchword in mysql

Tags: livesearch

I working on a little snippet, a live search with MySQL.

Now i think it could be nice to store/save which searchword the user, did the search on.

Example:

User search on

My new book

Then i want to store that to my databse.

The problem is with my script right now, where i trig the ajax on keyup. Then it will store.

> M My My N My Ne My New .... and so on..

and so on, how can i come around this and only store the hole line ..?

```
$(function() {
    $("#searchword").keyup(function(){
        var text = $(this).val();
        if (text != ' ') {
            $('#result').html(" ");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'livesearch.php',
                data: { 'search': text },
                success: function(dataReturn) {
                    $('#result').html(dataReturn);
                }
            });
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: Would be helpful to see the javascript code you're using. You can use a setTimeout and clearTimeout implementation to only save the data when user has stopped typing for a few seconds.

Comment: Would that work ? - I mean if the user search for "My new Book" and nothing comes up, then the user leaves my homepage. and if the timer is 2 sec, will it then save the search word?

Comment: @owaisafaq I have added my jquery :)

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Hello my friend, i have noget finished the script yet, but yes i think i'll just add a timer before store it in the mysql..

Comment: Awesome. Accept the answer if it works for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a `storeText(txt,time)` function that will take your text as first param and time to wait before sending ajax as second param. You can change the second parameter as per your need. Add your ajax call in the function below my comment and you're good to go.

```
$(function() {
    $("#searchword").keyup(function(){
        var text = $(this).val();
        if (text != ' ') {

            //THIS IS WHERE YOU CAN MODIFY THE TIME
            storeText(text,1000);

            $('#result').html(" ");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'livesearch.php',
                data: { 'search': text },
                success: function(dataReturn) {
                    $('#result').html(dataReturn);
                }
            });
        }
     });
});

var timer;
function storeText(txt,time){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){

        //ADD YOUR SAVE QUERY AJAX HERE

    },time);
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle to see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/3n2L2v6g/
Try typing anything in the text box, it waits 1000ms before executing the code where your ajax would be.